# Groupby and drop groups based on multiple conditions in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as seen below (w/ more columns but these are the only relevant columns)

```
order_id    product_id  purchase_value
1234.       23546.0.    50.
1234.       23546.0     20.
5678.       43244.0.    25.
```

I am trying to groupby order_id but only get orders where the purchase value for a specific product_id is a set amount.

Something like this: `groupby[order_id] where [product_id] = 23546, and [purchase_value] = 50`

I've tried

```
df = df[df['order_id'].eq('product_id').groupby(df['order_id']).transform('any')]
```

This works to filter on one column but I can't seem to figure out how to make this apply to multiple columns

Answer (score 2):

In your solution chain mask by `&` for bitwise AND for get all groups if match at least one value:

```
mask = df['order_id'].eq(23546) & df['purchase_value'].eq(50)
df1 = mask.groupby(df['order_id']).transform('any')]
```

Or get all groups matching values and then filter original column `order_id` by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
mask = df['order_id'].eq(23546) & df['purchase_value'].eq(50)
groups = df.loc[mask, 'order_id']
df1 = df[df['order_id'].isin(groups)]
```

Comment: Thanks, does this work if [product_id] is a string?

Comment: @dinn_ - then use `df['order_id'].eq('some_string')`

Answer (score 2):

You can apply multiple filters to your data frame, and then use group by in the same line of code.

```
df1 = df[(df.product_id==23456) & (df.purchase_value==50)].groupby("order_id").transform('any')
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for but it returns a df with True or False instead of the actual data? How do I get this but with the values themselves

Comment: If you just want to see the data, then I don't think you need to groupby. Does this get you what you are looking for? df1 = df[(df.product_id==23456) & (df.purchase_value==50)]